# Firebase Function: Create & Save thumbnail of uploaded video from Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making one demo android app for video upload download. I have done uploading video in **Firebase Storage** and I am storing **downloadURL** in **Firebase Firestore.**

Here is my structure of database.

[image]

Now I wanted to store image which will be generate automatically using **Firebase Function**. I show some [samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/convert-images) for convert image but I didn't get any example to create thumb from video.

Can anyone help? That will be appreciated.

Comment: Always keep in mind that Cloud Functions for Firebase are mostly just Node.js scripts that run in a managed environment. So if you search [how to generate a thumbnail from a video in Node.js?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+generate+a+thumbnail+from+a+video+in+Node.js) you'll get a good start. This answer is specific to Cloud Functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750325/getting-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-using-cloud-functions-for-firebase